# How to avoid duplicate random number and select another one in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an Arraylist and an Array of integer like this,

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] number= {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

Now I want to toast the integers from this array evertime I click a button with out any repeatation. After toasting every number from this array I want to toast 'Finished', my logic in onclick listener is here:

```
Random r = new Random();

            int i1=r.nextInt(number.length-0) + 0;
            if(!ar.contains(i1)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+i1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ar.add(i1);
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

but this didnt come to my way, It doesnt repeat any number but if it gets a duplicate number in the second click then it is toasting finished, but I want to toast it after every number from the integer array are toasted, wat should be my modified logic?

Comment: If you want 'Finished' to appear every time, don't put it in a conditional block(aka 'else')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar= new ArrayList<Integer>();
int[] number= {0,1,2,3,4,5};
for (int i : number) {
    ar.add(i);
}

Random r = new Random();

// repeat this part and you will never have duplicate numbers
int select = r.nextInt(ar.size());
int random = ar.get(select);
ar.remove(select);
```

Comment: It works, but after 2 or 3 button click this is causinf force close with index out of bound exception in ar.remove(random)

Comment: Updated: Should be ar.remove(select) and not ar.remove(random) due to API conflict when passing in an int value

Answer (score 2):

```
LinkedList<Integer> ar = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int[] number = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (int i : number) 
        ar.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(ar);


    //every time you click:
    if (ar.isEmpty()) { 
        //toast finished
    } else {
        Integer pop = ar.pop();
        //toast pop
    }
```

Comment: There is no method called pop here, please correct your answer, i think it will work

Comment: @Reyjohn List doesn't have a pop method, but LinkedList does.

Comment: LinkedList implements Queue. By the way that was only an example, you just need to shuffle the list and take the elements one at a time